# "openTlsConnect"Certification with CA and openTlsConnect

Tags: java, debugging, ssl

I'm working on software project, where I have the task to make a Proxi, which works like a client. This Clientproxi is running in java on win10 and communicates with embedded Serviceregistry Yocto-Linux and must building a safe external connections over HTTP(s) with certivicateexchange TLS1.2. I'm implementing and working with bouncycastlelibraries and have the following done:

```
    UnsecureHttpExecutor unsecureHttpExecutor = new UnsecureHttpExecutor();// Connection for external Clientservices
    logger.debug("Try to connect!");
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", "/auth");// simple GET /auth -for REST
    logger.debug("http.request: \n" + httpRequest.toString());
        
    
    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = unsecureHttpExecutor.executeRequest(httpRequest);// createHttpClient(); connectHttpClient();
        String mibIdentifierJson = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        logger.debug("This is MIBIdentifierJson:\n" + mibIdentifierJson);
        ResponseObject responseObject = JsonUtils.objectMapper().readValue(mibIdentifierJson, ResponseObject.class);
        logger.debug("JSONUtils" + JsonUtils.objectMapper().readValue(mibIdentifierJson, ResponseObject.class).toString());
       
        
        
        ClientContext clientContext = null;
        RegistrationProcess registrationProcess = new RegistrationProcess();
        logger.debug("Here is all ok!?");
        RegistrationResult registrationResult = registrationProcess.registerNewClient(); //<-- Here are the question        

//__________________________________________________________________________

 public RegistrationResult registerNewClient(ClientContext clientContext) {
       RegistrationResult registrationResult = null;

        try {
            
            createHttpClient();

            // create KeyPair, CSR and Self-Signed certificate which will be send to server during tls handshake (see MSC_002)
            KeyPair keyPair = CertificateUtils.generateKeyPair();
            //L.d("KeyPair abgeschlossen");
            logger.debug("KeyPair abgeschlossen KeyPair: " + keyPair.toString());
            PKCS10CertificationRequest certificationRequest = CertificateUtils.createCertificationRequest(/*clientContext.getAppName()*/"Testapp", keyPair);
            logger.debug("PKCS10CertificationRequest erfolgreich abgeschlossen");
            //L.d("PKCS10CertificationRequest erfolgreich abgeschlossen"
            X509CertificateHolder selfSignedCertificate = CertificateUtils.selfSignCertificate(certificationRequest, keyPair.getPrivate());
            //L.d("X509 Selbstsigniertes");
            
            logger.debug("X509 Selbstsigniertes Certifikat erstellt" + selfSignedCertificate.toString());
            openTlsConnect(selfSignedCertificate, keyPair.getPrivate());
```

---

I get following log

```
08:30:15.264 [main] DEBUG [main][connect()] - Try to connect!                                                               
08:30:15.268 [main] DEBUG [main][connect()] - http.request:                                                             GET /auth []                                                                                                                
08:30:15.296 [main] DEBUG [main][connect()] - Das ist der MIBIdentifierJson:                                            {"data":[{"id":"","name":"this is the auth-service of ViWi-ServiceRegistry","uri":"auth\/"}],"status":"ok","timestamp":1002380}                                                                                                                     
08:30:15.401 [main] DEBUG [main][connect()] - JSONUtilsCommunication.ResponseObject@6321e813                                
08:30:15.402 [main] DEBUG [main][connect()] - Hier noch alles gut!                                                          
08:30:15.598 [main] DEBUG [Registrationprocess] - KeyPair abgeschlossen KeyPair: java.security.KeyPair@77167fb7
08:30:15.619 [main] DEBUG [Registrationprocess] - PKCS10CertificationRequest erfolgreich abgeschlossen                  
08:30:15.626 [main] DEBUG [Registrationprocess] - X509 Selbstsigniertes Certifikat erstelltorg.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder@ad1a4e8d                                                                                                 Registration started                                                                                                    RegistrationSocked erstellt                                                                                             
08:30:15.627 [main] DEBUG Registrationsocked] - Connect registration socket using timeout: 3000
08:30:15.638 [main] DEBUG Registrationsocked] - Client Inputstream: %s                                                                                                                                                                          
08:30:15.638 [main] DEBUG Registrationsocked] - Client Outputstream: %s                                                                                                                                                                         
08:30:15.639 [main] DEBUG Registrationsocked] - TlsClientProtocol                                                       
08:30:15.639 [main] DEBUG Registrationsocked] - connect now via tls                                                     
08:30:15.639 [main] DEBUG Registrationsocked] - TLS Client:                                                             Registration.RegistrationTlsClient@441772e                                                                              
08:30:15.639 [main] DEBUG Registrationsocked] - TLS Client:                                                             Registration.RegistrationTlsClient$1@14dd9eb7                                                                           java.io.IOException: Internal TLS error, this could be an attackCould not perform registration process.
```

the problem lays in the method openTLSConnection and I don't know what I done wrong. Maybe it gives another way to get an TLS connection or clientconnection. thanks forward for comments!

Comment: i have debbuged and the system shows me the bug in the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was right but should be the port 443.